# wxwidgets/wxpython; shadow window

Tags: wxwidgets, shadow

I am wondering if it is possible to shadow (dimm?) the window in wx? Transparent background may do this trick, but so far I have not been able to.

regards

[shadowed window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vy1n.png)

[before shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAHdY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable the window, which would grey it out.

If you really just want to dim it, creating a grey half-transparent (i.e. using `SetTransparent()`) window over it is probably the best way to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For some reason, disabling the window blacks out (not grey out) with my system. Now I know, that I can SetTransparent the entire window. I was trying to set transparent background,

Comment: @jovian, What system/window manager/theme do you use for testing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My system is Debian testing AMD64, xfce. It does not looks like that transparent is supported. (???)